# White bar between my nav bar and main text?

Tags: css, html

After looking on stackoverflow for really long i could not find an answer to my question, so that's why i am asking it instead!

There's a strange white part between my navigation bar and main container, which i tested by just typing a under the bar

This is my code:

```css
body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

body {
 background-color: gray;
}

#wrapper {
 
 margin: 32px 160px 0 160px;
 background-color: white;
 height: 90%;
 

}

#nav {
 background-color: #48D1CC;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
 margin: -7px 4px 1px 0;
 background-color: #48D1CC;
 width: 19.5%;
 height: 42px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
}

#nav a {
 line-height: 42px;
 font-family: arial, serif;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
 background-color: #40E0D0;
}

#right {
 margin: 0;
 width: 15%;
 height: 10px;
 color: black;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="A test homepage"/>
<meta name="keyword" content="This is a few test key words"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
 <ul>
 <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
 <a href="index.html"><li>Help</li></a>
 <a href="index.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
 <a href="index.html"><li>Forum</li></a>
 <a href="index.html"><li>Info</li></a>
 </ul>
  </div>
  a
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript, you have it disabled</noscript>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

I am not sure why this happens, so some help would be great to have.

Comment: your gap is caused by natural bottom margin on the `#nav ul` - try setting it to 0 to fix your issue. Also, you need `li` as direct child of `ul` so swap your `li` and `a` tags around

Comment: Have a look at [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) to see why the ul margin affects the text outside the parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ul has a `16px` bottom margin

```
#nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

**NOTE** the next time you face a similar problem try using Chrome Dev Tools (prssing f12) or FireBug to analyze the elements with an unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Your `<ul>` tag is adding padding by default. Override it by adding:

```
ul{
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. New to this platform, so still learning to comment :)